# ESP32 wifi module

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, esp32

I want to connect my arduino uno rev3 to wifi. The best option I found was esp8266. After searching about it I found that it is succeeded by esp32. But I am not able to find much information about it. So I just wanted to ask if esp32 module exists as a addon to arduino or is it a board on its own. It will be really helpful if somebody can send the link from where I can buy this module(and not the board) and how to connect it to arduino.

Comment: Its called an ESP32 not an EP32 that might help your searches.

Comment: it is a "board" on it's own, that some people use the integrated UART with, to make it talk to AVRs using factory AT firmware, but it can run it's own sketch. it will work fine for you and if running stand-alone, is actually a better option then the venerable 8266 in terms of un-interupted CPU, HTTPS, more RAM, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESP32 is not a replacement for the ESP8266.  There is quite a bit of info out there, but mostly in Chinese.  If you were to use an ESP32 to provide WIFI its like using a Formula 1 car as a mobility scooter (Rascal in American?) It will do the job, but its really not suitable.

You can buy ESP32 on eBay or AliExpress, but really you shouldn't for this task.  Stick with an ESP8266.

BTW People will mark this as off topic, because it isn't strictly Arduino related.

Comment: So you are saying that esp32 is a fullblown board and not just available as a module like esp8266 module?

Comment: ESP32's seem to be available in similar module packaging as ESP8266's.  It's not that one couldn't work, it's that it's not *necessary* and being newer means less support and more issues you can run into, fewer tutorials you can be confident will work unchanged, etc.